# Missing artifact com.epam.reportportal:agent-java-testng:jar:5.0.4

Tags: pom.xml, reportportal

While integrating the report portal with your testng project, we need epam.reportpotal dependencies, On adding the reportportal dependency I am facing the following error in pom.xml dependency :
it says : Missing artifact com.epam.reportportal:agent-java-testng:jar:5.0.4

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this you need to add the following repositories in your pom.xml file as mentioned on github(https://github.com/reportportal/agent-java-testNG)

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>bintray-epam-reportportal</id>
            <name>bintray</name>
            <url>http://dl.bintray.com/epam/reportportal</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```